# Android UI XML Layout

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've created textview layout into main.xml, i want to see effects onto emulator, but i did not get my changes, it shows old result when i run my app into emulator.....

eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:text="@string/hello"/>
```

strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello, Android! I am a string resource!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Hello, Android</string>
</resources>
```

Please help if anyone know..............

Comment: what kind of effects? what have you tried? give us some code and more explainations because I don't really understand what you want to do...

Comment: hi folks, i'm new to android i've simple created a HelloAndroid application i want to try with xml layout. i've done it through developer guideline but after running the app it does not show the content that i've written into string.xml

Answer (score 0):

You probaly need to set the contentView of your Activity using the setContentView() to point to the new layout

```
public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }
}
```

See more under "Upgrade the UI to an XML Layout"
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Comment: hi folks, i'm new to android i've simple created a HelloAndroid application i want to try with xml layout. i've done it through developer guideline but after running the app it does not show the content that i've written into string.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you want dynamically change the text in your text view you need:

- set the content view for your activity:

  ```
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  ```
- get a reference to the TextView object:

  ```
  TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
  ```
- assing a new value:

  ```
  tv.setText(R.string.app_name);
  ```

Comment: Could you tell me the meaning of "v." in this line TextView tv= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
?

Comment: oops, missed it. meant to write just findViewById().